# Standards for HD displays

Tags: css

What are some standars for adjusting site for retine hd displays?
Since we can detec it using

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

what are the recommended practics for it?
Also are there ways how to check how site looks on retina hd display without actually having it?

Answer (score 1):

No. Do not try to outsmart your clients. Instead leave the choice to them.

You *offer* different resolutions by means of the `srcset` property. Easiest is to simply use it in ordinary `<img>` tags in combination with the `sizes` attribute or a size definition by means of css. That way the browser can select the resolution best suited for the current situation and things like screen resolution, size and network bandwidth can *all* be considered.

A simple description is offered by the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Example_3_Using_the_srcset_attribute).